# Uncrustify - How to not add space between =>

Tags: formatting, salesforce, apex, uncrustify

In apex we use `=>` when defining maps.  It is invalid syntax to have a space in between such as `= >`.

I have tried the following settings all of which result in a space between.

```
sp_compare = ignore
sp_inside_angle = ignore
sp_assign = ignore
sp_assign_default = ignore
sp_after_assign = ignore
```

Ideally I would have space around = when in assignments and comparisons, but would be interested in any solutions that solve my issue.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No we don't support apex so unless java gets that operator we won't add support for that in our code.

As we did not for Nvidias '<<<' operators, see https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify/issues/1965#issuecomment-413015511 where I showed a possibility to add you own operators in your local build.